# group all directly and indirectly related records using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, many-to-many, relationship

thanks in advance:

I am trying to generate a group identifier in a many to many relationship table which has 2 columns defining IDs of parent entities and a child entities:

Example dataframe below: (parent (p), and child (c))

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,7],[1,3],[1,4],[3,2],[5,1],[6,0]]))
df.columns= ['p', 'c']
```

Table looks like below:

```
p  c
1  7
1  3
1  4
3  2
5  1
6  0
```

I am trying to get all directly and indirectly linked records in a group. For example:

- Parent Record 1 is parent of [7,3,4], and
- Parent Record 5 is the parent of 1
- Parent Record 3 has is parent of 2 and 2 is grand-child of 1

So I want to generate an ID for all related record. where parent record 6 is not related to any record, I will move it to another group, a sample result like below:

```
p  c  grp
1  7  A
1  3  A
1  4  A
3  2  A
5  1  A
6  0  B
```

My current way of thinking :

For each record, if it doesn't have a group yet:

- Getting all directly related record IDs
- Then for each directly related record IDs Recursively perform the same function to find all related record for the child until they have no child record
- Then assign a group to the group of record IDs (list)

I am not sure if it is the right way to do it, and it seemed to be unnecessarily slow, and I have to pass down all the parent records in the chain to the child record in order for it not to perform the same search for already searched results.

Would really appreciate if someone can give me a better solution. :)

Comment: You might be better suited to using a graph library to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/index.html)

```
import networkx as nx

G=nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 'c', 'p')
l=list(nx.connected_components(G))
dfmap=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(l)
dfmap.index=['B','A']
dfmap=dfmap.stack()
d=dict(list(zip(dfmap.values.astype(int),dfmap.index.get_level_values(0))))
df['grp']=df.replace(d).p
df
Out[14]: 
   p  c grp
0  1  7   A
1  1  3   A
2  1  4   A
3  3  2   A
4  5  1   A
5  6  0   B
```

More Info

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
nx.draw(G)
```

[image]

Comment: @AnthonySun Yw~ , add more information about the relation

Comment: I was headed down this route.  I didn't think to convert the connected_components list back to a dataframe.  Nice. +1

Comment: this is a pretty clueless questions, say if a don't want to group by hard coded A and B, can I just comment out below line dfmap.index=['B','A']?

Comment: @AnthonySun yes you can , then will return 0 and 1

Comment: Convenient tips for latecomers：“from_pandas_dataframe” has been deprecated In networkx 2.0+ .  Instead, you can use “from_pandas_edgelist”.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post my solution because it is faster (for this small dataset) and hoping someone will make it more efficient.

```
import netowrkx as nx
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,7],[1,3],[1,4],[3,2],[5,1],[6,0]]))
df.columns= ['p', 'c']

G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 'p','c')
subgraphs = list(nx.connected_components(G))
grouplist = list('BA')

def defineGrouping(x):
    return grouplist[[n for n,i in enumerate(subgraphs) if x in i][0]]

df['grp'] = df.c.map(defineGrouping)
df
```

Output:

```
   p  c grp
0  1  7   A
1  1  3   A
2  1  4   A
3  3  2   A
4  5  1   A
5  6  0   B
```

#### Timing because I suspected that Pandas overhead is significant

@Wen's method converting connected_components back to pandas dataframe

> 100 loops, best of 3: 6.47 ms per loop

This method of using list comprehension and enumerate:

> 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.14 ms per loop

Comment: thanks, will experiment with it as well. I initially used pandas cause I am reading file from a csv, and it is easier. will give np array a try. I am still quite new in python, so far experience has been pretty positive. :) thank you all for your help.